Cannot build kotlinx.coroutines with "No matching toolchains found" error
Cannot build the kotlinx.coroutines project. As it described in their contribution doc, just 'build' should be enough. It stops almost immediately. What should I check?
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':kotlinx-coroutines-core:compileKotlinJvm'.
> No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=11, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific} for WINDOWS on x86_64.
   > No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.

What JVMs I have:
PS C:\a\kotlinx.coroutines> ./gradlew -q javaToolchains
Using Kotlin compiler version: 2.0.0

 + Options
     | Auto-detection:     Enabled
     | Auto-download:      Enabled

 + Amazon Corretto JDK 19.0.2+7-FR
     | Location:           C:\Users\igort\.jdks\corretto-19.0.2
     | Language Version:   19
     | Vendor:             Amazon Corretto
     | Architecture:       amd64
     | Is JDK:             true
     | Detected by:        IntelliJ IDEA

 + OpenJDK 23+37-2369
     | Location:           C:\Users\igort\.jdks\openjdk-23
     | Language Version:   23
     | Vendor:             Oracle
     | Architecture:       amd64
     | Is JDK:             true
     | Detected by:        IntelliJ IDEA

 + Oracle JDK 21.0.4+8-LTS-274
     | Location:           C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21
     | Language Version:   21
     | Vendor:             Oracle
     | Architecture:       amd64
     | Is JDK:             true
     | Detected by:        Current JVM

PS C:\a\kotlinx.coroutines>

PS C:\a\kotlinx.coroutines> echo $env:JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21
PS C:\a\kotlinx.coroutines> ls $env:JAVA_HOME


    Directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM                bin
d-----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM                conf
d-----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM                include
d-----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM                jmods
d-----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM                legal
d-----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM                lib
-a----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM           6186 LICENSE
-a----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM            290 README
-a----         10/3/2024   1:23 PM           1282 release


PS C:\a\kotlinx.coroutines>

That's Windows, Android Studio and Android SDK are installed, I can build projects.
Upd: The gradle scan https://scans.gradle.com/s/vv4qyafzjc2pw

The version of a toolchain is explicitly requested here and probably somewhere else.
gradle.properties: jdk_toolchain_version=11

So installing Oracle JDK11 fixes the problem.

I faced a somewhat similiar scenario when trying to run a Kotlin application. What solved it for me was adding the following snippet to the settings.gradle.kts file
plugins {
    id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version("0.8.0")
}

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories
